# CanoScanLiDE 25 driver for OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, scanner, drivers, canon-lide

The Canon driver says "not supported" – is there any way to keep using this device after a Mountain Lion upgrade from Snow Leopard?

The inability to use the peripheral was an unexpected side-effect of upgrading… anybody out there successfully scanning on 10.8, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver for Snow leopard works fine.

I installed both the CanoScanToolBox X (cstbosx4934ej4.dmg) and the driver (lide25osx11031en.dmg). Then it asked me to restart.

Once that one done, I opened Image Capture and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The driver for Mac OS X Snow Leopard works fine with OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: You tried it? Have you tried the software too? I thought that had some PPC code in it, which is unsupported starting from Lion... any more info on your setup you could share?

Answer (score 0):

I just read something on the canon US support page and found out that you can use the Canoscan 25 without a driver. Just use your Preview program to import from scanner. Awesome;)

Comment: Not really awesome considering how many features and how much control you lose Vs having the full driver installed..